# Extracting consecutive integers from a list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `[1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]` where in this list, I have two separate sublists of consecutive integers; namely, `[3, 4]` and `[8, 9, 10]`.

I need to write a function that can return these sublists, such as:

```py
array = [1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]
my_func(array)
>>>> [[3, 4], [8, 9, 10]]
```

I have a working solution, but I wondered if there wasn't something more simplistic?

```py
array = [1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10]
def my_func(arr):
    found = []
    for idx, elem in enumerate(arr):
        consecutive_elements = [item for sublist in found for item in sublist]
        if elem not in consecutive_elements:

            substring = [elem]
            count = 1
            while idx + count < len(arr):
                if arr[idx + count] == elem + count:
                    substring.append(arr[idx + count])
                    count += 1
                else:
                    break
            if len(substring) > 1:
                found.append(substring)

        else:
            continue

    return found

my_func(array)
>>>> [[3, 4], [8, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: CodeReview is a more appropriate place to post such queries.

Comment: Look at `itertools.groupby`. Hint: `for _, g in groupby(enumerate(your_list), lambda k: k[0] - k[1]):`